# What are the specifications of the NS-5?

Tags: i-robot-2004

I've done some research but couldn't find much at all regarding the *specifications* of the NS-5 units.  I know that they were made from some sort of alloy (because Sonny had 'denser alloy'), they were bi-pedal, received wireless updates from US Robotics (USR) and were about human height, but you've gotta admit that's pretty basic information.

I was wondering if anyone knew more **detailed specifications of the NS-5 units** e.g. height, maximum strength, computational specifications; basically as much information as is *canonically* available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original [www.irobotnow.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20040727014232/http://www.irobotnow.com/index.php) website offered the following information about the NS-5's specifications;

> - The NS-5's positronic brain can perform more than 6 trillion calculations per second
> - The NS-5 comes equipped with 1 terabyte of memory and direct access to the sea of data housed at URN.
> - In addition to being nearly 100% energy efficient, the NS-5, in a pinch, can provide up to 13 hours of power at 29.2/16.9A.
> - At a hair shy of six feet tall, the NS-5 goes any and everywhere you can.